# Make new partition table

Tags: partitioning

Gdisk shows that I have only MBR type partition table. Is there any solution to make a new partition table without losing my drives contents?

I want to install Ubuntu side of my Windows 7 that is installed.but Ubuntu installer doesn't show my partitions although I removed gpt stray.

Meantime my MBR boot is corrupted and I can't log in Windows.it's not the problem,but maybe related or cause of problem. I used fixparts,gdisk or anything else it was.I had to study 10 articles about this commands at day for the fear of losing data.

Is it practicable to solve the problem by recreating the partition table?

Or if I fix boot on MBR, Ubuntu will detect my partitions?

Answer (score 2):

On several occasions, I have re-created a partition table that was exactly the same as before, and the disk partitions magically appeared unharmed.  That was not my intent, but it happens that way.  The partition table editor makes changes to the partition table ONLY.  So if you took a screenshot of the partition table before making changes, you can just make it identical.  If you're guessing, then probably not.

A utility *could* examine a disk and figure out the beginning and ending of each partition and generate a proper table, but I don't have experience with any.

Finally, some OS's like MS Windows need to be *goosed* after having their tables tweaked.  Each version of windows seems to have it's own command to do this.  `fdisk c: /mbr`  was one example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repartition your hard drive, to set up new OS installation, you may want to use [GParted](http://gparted.org/) for this. In this app/system (as it boots the whole computer) you can decrease the size of the current system/partitions, to make place for a second one with moving data along on the disk.